# Directory-based projects in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, project

I have created a new project (from existing sources) in IntelliJ (10.5 community edition) and I selected to make it directory based. IntelliJ wanted to commit only one .iml file, which I did. However, now I can't seem to open the project on my other PC. What other files do I need to commit? Which should stay local?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please [refer to the FAQ](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23393067), you also need to commit most of the files from the `.idea` directory except `workspace.xml` and `tasks.xml` (and some others depending on your configuration, personal preferences and security considerations).

Comment: Cheers! Shame that idea doesn't add these files to repository automatically.